# Someone help me understand the square bracket in the following Python code?

Tags: python

```
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook("univ_list.xls")
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
for r in range(sh.nrows)[1:]: # line 4
    print sh.row(r)[:4] # line 5
```

What does `[1:]` mean in line 4? What does `[:4]` mean in line 5?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good Primer for Python Slice Notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation)

Comment: agreed ^^^^ this is answered above but without similar keywords

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example of what you're seeing on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_slicing#1991:_Python

It's called array slicing. `[1:]` gets all the items except for the first, and `[:4]` gets the first 4 items.

Comment: Good mnemonics for slicing can be found in Python docs, also mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation  ("One way to remember how slices work is to think of the indices as pointing between characters, with the left edge of the first character numbered 0.")

Answer (score 0):

[1:] means you just want to get the items from position 1 on in your list, string, etc.

[:4] means you want to get up to item 4 in your string or list.

Remember, numbering starts at 0.

so in f = 'apple', f[0]='a', f[1]='p', f[1:]='pple'

Read up on slice notation -- there's a lot more you can do with that.